# Stopping Previous Scripts

Tags: python, function

Hello so what i would like to do is something that  i cannot figure out and I don't even know if possible.In the case of this question I will write some new code as an example as mine is confusing #right now, So what I like to do is stop a function if a statement in a different function is true so

```
list1= 'k','E','W','L'
def add_or_remove():
    user_input= input()
    Determine(user_input)
    list1.remove(user_input)
    print("remove")

def Determine(user_input)
    if user_input=="W": 
       print("do no remove")  <--- how do i stop here so it doesnt list1.remove in other function
```

i thought of exit() and such but i do not want to exit the program I just want to stop the other operations in the beginning function. Please ignore any errors as i just wrote this to express my question and not for actual code

Answer (score 0):

Make the Determine() function return a value depending on the input

```
def add_or_remove():
    user_input= input()
    if Determine(user_input) != -1
        list1.remove(user_input)
    print("remove")

def Determine(user_input)
    if user_input=="W": 
       return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return` statement in `Determine` function and check the returned value in `add_or_remove()` function:

```
list1= 'k','E','W','L'
def add_or_remove():
    user_input= input()
    if Determine(user_input) != "NO":  #if the returned value is not "NO" then remove
       list1.remove(user_input)
       print("remove")

def Determine(user_input)
    if user_input=="W": 
       print("do no remove")
       return "NO"           #return this if `user_input=="W"` is `True`
```